# how string Constant pool works in java

Tags: java, string

First i got a doubt that, when I create a string as

```
String s = new String("Stack");
```

whether `"Stack"` is saved in String Constant pool or not?

but this post : [what happens with new String("") in String Constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621958/what-happens-with-new-string-in-string-constant-pool) tell that it is not.

but according to answers of this post : [where do actual parameters in java store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676143/where-do-actual-parameters-in-java-store)  tell that it is present in Constant pool.

Please give a clarification on this.

Comment: You are misreading the answers there. Read them again. No contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

If you do:

```
String s = "Stack";
```

.. then the literal string "Stack" is, in fact, a part of the constant string pool. When you do:

```
String s = new String("Stack");
```

... however, the original literal string "Stack" is a part of the string pool, but the use of "new" here forces a copy to be constructed that is not in the constant pool.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s=new String("Stack");
```

For the above statement, there will be a String literal `Stack` created in the constant pool, and in the heap, there will be another `String` object which will be referred by reference `s`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like this:

```
String a = "ang";

String b = "ang";
```

Both String a and b point to same "ang". Reference would be same because they both point to "ang" in string pool.

But when you do:

```
String a = new String("ang");
String b = new String("ang");
```

They both point to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

> but this post : what happens with new String("") in String Constant pool tell that it is not.

No it doesn't. See the first comment: 'Both. Both. Both.' Or the accepted answer: "'intern()' or string literal".

> but according to answers of this post : where do actual parameters in java store tell that it is present in Constant pool.

Correct. The compiler puts the string literals there, and intern() puts dynamic strings there.