# Build a String with String Operators

Tags: java

In this example I thought that the result was true. I thought that the variable stored in the string pool. 
The answer was: returns false because the two String objects are not the same in memory. One comes directly from the string pool and the other comes from building using String operations.

```
String a = "";
 a += 2;
 a += 'c';
 a += false;
 if ( a == "2cfalse") System.out.println("==");
```

I do not understand where the variable a was stored

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that a specific string will be pulled from the string pool.

Comment: @cricket_007:  No, absolutely not.  It's not asking anything about that. It's asking about whether or not `a` is interned.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8914878/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/21850156/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/21676143/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/14150628/1065197 and on...

Comment: @Makato - Still, the answer if false for reasons discussed in that post

Comment: @cricket_007: I am ***well*** aware as to why the result is `false`, but I maintain that  *isn't* the point of this question.

Comment: Great, let's continue upvoting a duplicate Q/A...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:  To be blunt, I'm enjoying the answer posed here more so than I am the other one.  It explains the scenario a fair bit clearer.  Even if they are dupes, that doesn't make this question *bad*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I do not agree to the duplicate flag, so yes, I will continue upvoting. The question you marked this as a duplicate of does not go in depth about the workings of a string pool when using string operators, this one does.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg Check the last sentence of the accepted answer. `then while a String will exist with the value test, said String will not exist in the pool as the literal "test" has never occurred.`. Actually that is fullfully answering the question here.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg I disagree with you too. The accepted answer covers this clearly in this part: *Strings are only put in the pool when they are interned explicitly or by the class's use of a literal. So if you have, for example, this scenario `String test = new String(te) + new String(st)`* and OP's piece of code doesn't belong to a literal string but to the concatenation of literal strings, thus not being stored in the string pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so two responses to this. First, the ethically correct one, do never test strings with `==`, always use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Secondly, it's true that indeed, `"a" == "a"` because the strings are stored in, as you call it, the same pool. The problem here is that you append to it. Appending to a string causes it to become a different string, which is not stored in the string pool. The string pool is only generated on-compile, and as the second string is calculated on runtime, it won't match the one generated on-compile.

Imagine a string-pool to work like this:

```
a = "test";
b = "te";
c = "st";
d = "test";
```

The compiler translates this into

```
sp1 = "test";
sp2 = "te";
sp3 = "st";
a = sp1;
b = sp2;
c = sp3;
d = sp1;
```

Now `==` will check if two variables refer to the same sp. If you run `b + c` java will not go back and check if any of the sp's is the same as that. It only does that on compile.